# Explain Alternative PHP For Loop Syntax: for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 10; $j += $i, print $i, $i++);

Tags: php, for-loop

This example has been given as an alternative example (example 4 to be precise) for writing `for` loops on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

```
for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 10; $j += $i, print $i, $i++);
```

I understand `for` loops, I just don’t understand why the variable, `$j`, is declared in this version of writing a for loop that prints the numbers 1 to 10.

FYI: Removing the variable from the for loop makes absolutely no difference to the result.

Comment: it doesn't seem the `j` is doing anything beside sum the `i` ...o.O

Comment: Well it seems that the documentation adopted a style similar to the language itself. Bloated and full of gotchas.

Comment: @Richard: The same thing is possible in every language I know that uses for-loops with this syntax... C, C++, Java, JavaScript, and probably many of those listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages

Comment: @Jost I was critisizing the documentation, not this particular syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it's just here for illustrate the fact that you can use multiple statement with commas.
It's useless here but show an example of the syntax for :

> [...] Each of the expressions can be empty or contain multiple expressions separated by commas. In expr2, all expressions separated by a comma are evaluated but the result is taken from the last part. [...]

Answer (score 3):

While it doesn't seem to be necessary in this example. It appears that `$j` is storing the summation of the iterations:

```
 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55
```

Which can be useful in some situations. So that would mean this style of looping is for the equivalent of doing several operations on each iteration, such as getting the summation, average, largest value, etc. The point of the example is that you can apply several statements separated by commas.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

```
for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 10; $j += $i, print $i, $i++);
```

for loops takes three part separated by semicolon (;).

1. Initialize
2. Compare and test
3. Increment or Decrements.

   - Here $i=1, $j=0 is initialization.
   - $i<=10; is compare and test
   - $j += $i, print $i, $i++ is increment or decrements part

Now in your increment or decrements part you have three task.
 1. is increment $j with last $i
 2. print $i
 3. increment $i by 1

> So in your program $j is not useful. Because it is not taking part of
>   either print or compare and test.

So the loop is just very simple if you remove $j from every where and write it as

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    print $i;
}
```

But that $j variable could be used after the loop where from you have taken this code block.

**LIKE**

```
for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 10; $j += $i, print $i, $i++); 
print $j;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can remove $j and have the same result:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; print $i, $i++);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).